# How do we calculate the path size (PS) for Path Size Logit Model?

Tags: logit, clogit, mlogit

I am using Multinomial Logit model for the discrete choice analysis, in which user chooses a route among other available paths. This is intended to determine the utility of those routes. As these alternatives should be mutually exclusive, as per assumption of MNL model, this is not true. It is because some of the alternatives have common links between them. In order to correct this, path size correction should be used, which is attached below (from previous studies).
[image]

What I am confused about is the terms in denominator. If I assume gamma to be 0, then how should PS be calculated?

Here is another snapshot of the study, which attempts to calculate the PS.

[image]

I tried to calculate PS for above figure from both ways, but getting different answers. I would be glad if any of you, who have knowledge on this topic, could guide me to find PS for the above attached route, by the use of formula in the first snapshot. (Assuming C=4 AND delta=1)

Comment: If you are referring to the exponent on (Li/Lj) in the denominator, anything raised to the power of 0 is 1 (i.e., $-3^0=1$, $5^0=1$, $17^0=1$, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I realized that these two are same, i.e. second snapshot is the condition when gamma=0 is used in the first snapshot. I planning to use the gamma=0, as it will simplify the calculation. I was wondering if it have some value>1, how the calculation could be done.